# What does "taped" mean in this sentence?

Tags: sports

I'm reading Michael Lewis's *The Blind Side*. In Chapter Three, when Ole Miss basketball team lost a game and came back to campus, the coach said to his players:

> *Dressed, stretched, and taped. Thirty minutes.*

What does the "*taped*" mean here?

Answer (score 5):

Players of active sports like basketball use adhesive tape to protect injuries or to restrict joint movement to prevent sprains.  So after the lost game, the coach tells the team to get ready for practice.  They have thirty minutes to get dressed in their uniforms, do their stretches to warm up, and put on the adhesive tape they need to play safely.